# Authenticate method is deprecated in google drive api (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I've used google drive api v3 earlier without any issue now after long time I'm using it again to authenticate user with access token but when I call authenticate method of google drive client it states this method is deprecated, also I've observed google has changed many other features.

```
$file = 'credentials.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    ]);
$client->setAuthConfig($file);
if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken(json_decode($accessToken, true));
    return $client;
}
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
<a href="<?php echo $authUrl; ?>">Login</a>
```

as authenticate is giving null response so its not letting to set access token and giving error json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for the new command, instead use:

```
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
```